# SolrNet: What is the correct way to specify Boost values at index time?

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr-boost

I am going to index documents that will have Boost values from 1 to 10. One way is to simply use AddWithBoost(*doc* , *boostvalue*) . But is this the correct way? Do I need to translate the scale (1 - 10) to some other range in order to make sure that document with boost value 10   is ranked higher than one with value 9 for some query? I guess  what I am looking for is the standard way of using Boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddWithBoost` boosts documents at index-time. You can also boost fields at index-time by appending a boost value to the property attribute, e.g.:

```
[SolrField("thesolrfield", Boost = 20)]
public string Something { get; set; }
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531533/lucene-lucene-net-document-setboost-values) and the [Lucene similarity docs](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) for more information on using boosts.