# How to create content ranking search in Lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have created the Lucene.net project with index and searched data (fuzzy search and wildcard search). Now I want to prioritize the search result. How to rank the content?

For fuzzy search:

```
Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
finalQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

For wildcard search:

```
Query query1 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
finalQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Comment: for fuzzy search  Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
            finalQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
for wildcardsearch  Query query1 = new WildcardQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
            finalQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

Comment: Update your question, not add as a comment..

Comment: i have update in question

Answer (score 0):

Your results should have a score property --> ranking. 
Results are usually already ordered by score.
To define the ranking, see lucene documentation and maybe use google to find examples of how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm. There you have the documentation [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html)

You can "boost" your document by calling

`doc.SetBoost(0.1);`

More about that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531533/lucene-lucene-net-document-setboost-values)